# How do I create an image button - Python

Tags: python, button, tkinter

For the buttons, I want to change the "text" to be "images"
e.g picture of a eraser instead of text saying eraser.

Here is the Section of Code:

```
def __init__(self):

    self.root = Tk()

    self.choose_size_button = Scale(self.root, from_=1, to=15, orient=HORIZONTAL) 
    self.choose_size_button.grid(row=0, column=1)

    self.draw_button = Button(self.root, text='Draw', command=self.use_draw) 
    self.draw_button.grid(row=0, column=2)

    self.color_button = Button(self.root, text='Colour', command=self.choose_color) 
    self.color_button.grid(row=0, column=3)

    self.eraser_button = Button(self.root, text='Eraser', command=self.use_eraser)
    self.eraser_button.grid(row=0, column=4)

    self.c = Canvas(self.root, bg='white', width=650, height=600) 
    self.c.grid(row=1, columnspan=5)

    self.setup() 
    self.root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use the tinkter to perform your task. You can pass image argument to the button.
For example:

```
import Tkinter as tk

class View(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.image = tk.PhotoImage(file="anyfile.gif")
        b = tk.Button(self, text=" ", image=self.image)
        b.pack(side="top")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    view = View(root)
    view.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: How would I add multiple picture buttons and make them do commands?

Comment: You mean you want multiple pictures in one button?? please elaborate your question

Comment: multiple buttons with one photo each

Comment: u mean each button should have same image?

Comment: I have 4 buttons. And I want 3 of them to have images as the button. So basically I want to use your code to make 3 more buttons, how would I do that? I also want to make the code do commands once I click on it

Answer (score 0):

You can use image argument of Button in tkinter.

For example; see this snippet:-

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
root = Tk()
img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open('your_image_path'))
b = Button(root, command = print('hello'), image = img)
b.pack()
b.place()
```